# How to increase width of Ext.Msg.Confirm message box

Tags: extjs

How to increase width of Ext.Msg.Confirm message box.

Answer (score 10):

To make all messages wider try this:

```
Ext.MessageBox.minWidth = 300;
```

Answer (score 1):

By defining the `width` option of [ExtJS.MessageBox.show()](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.MessageBox) method.

Comment: Thanx, Is this method predefined in ExtJS? If so, where can i find this method?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have a look at the API documentation I linked in my answer.

Comment: Still valid answer, also in ExtJS4

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ext.MessageBox.minWidth = 300;  please vote him up. I don't have the rep yet to vote that answer up myself.  The first answer simply pointed to docs that no longer exist for ExtJS 3,  and points to a method show() that may not be in use.

The answer #2 works perfectly for me, since I came here with the same question:

```
Ext.MessageBox.minWidth = 300;
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Warning', 'Are you sure?', function(btn)
{
    // this will execute if the user clicks Yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the function setWidth like :

```
Ext.Msg.setMinWidth(600)
```